# getting error while trying to get following of users via twitter API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter, twitter-login, twitter-api-v2

[i am trying to connect twitter API of getting friends (followers) of user via twitter's api with endpoint that mentioned here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVSXa.png)

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friends/list.json
```

Error that i am getting is that about cors, though i have manage it from browser side

Here is my code that i use for fetch user

```
const response = await fetch('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friends/list.json',{
            method: 'GET',
            headers : {
                "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
                'Authorization' : 'Bearer my_token'
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

The Twitter API does not support CORS and you cannot call it in a browser in this manner. You will need to use server-side code.

(additionally, the v1.1 API you are trying to use is a legacy API and you would be better to look at v2 - the equivalent is the [Follows lookup](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/users/follows/introduction) functionality)